# Unknown Accounts suddenly appearing in MetaMask wallet....?

Tags: ether, metamask, wallets, dapps, accounts

My MetaMask wallet has multiple accounts which I did not create. I have no idea how they there. 
Is my MetaMask wallet compromised? Or is this normal that MetaMask creates new wallet addresses when needed for certain transactions or webpages?
The unknown addresses are only visible in "Transfer between my accounts" which of course suggests that they are mine, but I cannot even access them or see the complete addresses. 
I have attached a screenshot below the above account that is blurred out is mine, the other accounts below the blue line are the ones unknown and unaccessible to me. I cannot edit/delete them.
If any is familiar whit this please advice me on what to do.
Thanks guys[image]

Comment: Created an Avalanche account and there were already transactions from a few months back. I am not sure why it is there.

Answer (score 2):

In that dialog Metamask is showing addresses that were used as recipients in previous transactions.

If you previously interacted with a dapp or contract they will appear there.

It seems bad that Metamask doesn't allow to see the full address.

Comment: Thank you Ismael you’re right that must be it since I mostly interacted with dapps and contracts. 

MetaMask should fix the not seeing the full address issue. It causes unnecessary panic.

Answer (score 1):

That definitely looks like a problem, have you given your priv key to anyone? left it on github?

Or, those are people you have sent eth or token to.

Comment: Nope I haven't given anyone my private key. I also haven't visited GitHub since creating the account so that can't be it either. These are people I have sent ETH or Token to??? Very strange shouldn't the addresses in this case be in the recent section as well? I have only sent it tokens to 4 addresses and those are not these. Strangely I am not missing any ETH or Tokens. But I will clear out the account to be safe. I was just wondering if this was normal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

me also happen but in different way. i created a new adding account in metamask but suddenly that new account have some small amount of 0.002eth. I checked in etherscan and found that it was transferred 4 month ago by somebody account. what going on i dont know.